# How to setup Sublime Text 3 to build script with MSYS bash?

Tags: bash, path, sublimetext3, msys

Hi i would like to know how to setup sublime text 3 build system to execute bash script threw MSYS bash.

I have try the following build system :

```
{
    "cmd"       : ["bash", "$file"],
    "selector"  : "source.shell",
    "path"      : "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin"
}
```

It does look to work, but it can't find gcc, i have try to add multiple path this way :

```
    "path"      : "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:C:/MinGW/bin"
```

But the **C: looks to break the thing**.
I have also try this :

```
    "path"      : ["C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin", "C:/MinGW/bin"]
```

But it fail also as path is waiting for a string only

```
     "path"      :"C\:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:C\:/MinGW/bin"
     "path"      :"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin\:C:/MinGW/bin"
     "path"      :"${C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin}:${C:/MinGW/bin}"
```

Also fail ...

```
     "path"      : "/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/c/MinGW/bin"
     "path"      : "/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/MinGW/bin"
```

Same for those ...

Any working suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `"path"      : "/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer SB87 ! yes this one work, but the pb is that it can't find gcc , so i am trying to find the way to link the 2 path MinGW\bin and msys\bin.

Comment: Try `"path"      : "/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/MinGW/bin"` so get rid of the `C:`

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work i have edited my post to include the 2 new test that fail !

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: i just get a line `2: gcc: command not found` when i only set /msys/bin.

Comment: what is the output of `which gcc` in terminal?

Comment: got this `/mingw/bin/gcc.exe`

Comment: Ah, reading [this](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) maybe you should set the `path` before you set the `cmd`? Also, have you tried `"path" : "$PATH:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/MinGW/bin"`?

Comment: Thanks a lot SB87 you did help me with your mac stuff. because it give me the idea to search in install package ... and ALLELUIA got this
https://github.com/macite/sublimebashbuildsystem/blob/master/Bash.sublime-build

Comment: Well done! Syntax can be hard to figure out, sometimes a simple example clarifies it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To **install msys bash with sublime text 3** you just have to copy this in
>   a new build system:

```
{
    "cmd"       : ["bash", "$file"],
    "selector"  : "source.shell",

    "windows": {
        "path"  : "$path;c:\\mingw\\bin;c:\\mingw\\msys\\1.0\\bin",
        "cmd"   : ["bash", "--login", "-i", "-c", "cd \"$file_path\"; \"$file\""]
    },

    "osx": {
        "path"  : "$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"
    }
}
```

thanks to macite :

https://github.com/macite/sublimebashbuildsystem/blob/master/Bash.sublime-build