# Error while trying to use C in SublimeText 3 (gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext3

It's the first time i try to use C in SublimeText 3 and i keep getting the same error when I run a simple C program:

I'm using windows 10 64 bit

```
"gcc" non � riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```

(this translates in: "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file")

```
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['gcc', 'prova.c', '-o', 'prova.exe', '&&', 'prova.exe']]
[dir: C:\Users\Giovanni\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS 
Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Gcc is installed in C<:\MinGW\bin and i have added the path to windows environmental variables as you can see here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVOgy.jpg.

I'm using the following build (it's copy-pasted from internet):

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

My pc runs windows 10 64 bit
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The path that Sublime is using is listed in the build output next to `[path: ` and it doesn't seem to mention `C:\MinGW\bin`; If you made that change after Sublime was already running, you may need to quit Sublime and restart it to get it to see the change.

Comment: Did you add the path in the "System Environment Variables" under the "Path" variable? If so try open cmd and try the command gcc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Sublime Text 3 to build script with MSYS bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139937/how-to-setup-sublime-text-3-to-build-script-with-msys-bash)

Answer (score 0):

The same had happened to me even after adding to the right path, this error wasn't coming when I run or ran it on command prompt but this error was being displayed in Sublime Text 3, all I had to do was to restart Sublime Text 3 and then a new error was displayed after trying to run a simple C Program saying No such directory or file because the file wasn't saved in the folder into which the Sublime Text 3 was looking for,...., that is, C:\Users\Admin in my case and therefore I saved the C Program file with extension as "c" ofcourse  in that folder and it worked!!!!